# Random java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null

Tags: java, spring, java-stream, concurrentmodification

I have a method that runs every 5 minutes and removes files from a cache

```
private HashMap<String, CachedFile> cache = new HashMap<>();

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 300000)
public void deleteFileCache() {

    //remove files last accessed > 12h
    cache.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> LocalDateTime.now().minus(12, ChronoUnit.HOURS)
            .isAfter(entry.getValue().getLastAccessed())).forEach(entry -> {
        File file = new File(tempFolder, entry.getKey());
        boolean deleted = file.delete();
    });

    //remove entries from HashMap
    cache.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> LocalDateTime.now().minus(12, ChronoUnit.HOURS)
            .isAfter(entry.getValue().getLastAccessed()));

    //if little space left remove oldest files
    long freeSpace = tempFolder.getFreeSpace();
    while (freeSpace < 6000000000L) {
        Optional<String> fileToDelete = cache.entrySet().stream()
                .min(Comparator.comparing(stringCachedFileEntry -> stringCachedFileEntry.getValue().getLastAccessed()))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey);

        fileToDelete.ifPresent(filename -> {
            new File(tempFolder, filename).delete();
            cache.remove(filename);
        });
        freeSpace = tempFolder.getFreeSpace();
    }
}
```

This method fails with a ConcurrentModificationException about 2-3 times a day. I am unable to see why since the method can only run once at the same time and I am not iterating at the same time as removing from the HashMap.

It fails at line `.min(Comparator.comparing(stringCachedFileEntry ->...`

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
        at java.util.HashMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1704) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:479) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.min(ReferencePipeline.java:520) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at ch.my.app.server.FileCacheService.deleteFileCache(FileCacheService.java:113) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace? This sounds interesting.

Comment: Is there another thread appending to this map?

Comment: As an aside you would probably want to write `6_000_000_000L` for readability.

Comment: If the scheduler uses different threads between runs, is something thread-safe such as `ConcurrentHashMap` necessary? And who adds to the map?

Comment: @user0000001  yes there are other threads  (Spring boot controller) reading and writing (no deletes) to the map. Why would it fail on the mentioned line of code?

Comment: @isADon It is difficult to say why that line in particular. I recommend that you switch your implementation to a `ConcurrentHashMap` and see if this yields better results. Any time you use a non-synchronized object with multiple threads, you will run into these kinds of problems.

Comment: @isADon: in the presence of concurrent modification (as you said, other threads might add elements while this is running) a `HashMap` may produce basically any weird behaviour possible. It will *try* to throw a ConcurrentModificationException, but that's your *best case*. Use a `ConcurrentHashMap` or guard any possible modification with the appropriate tools (`synchronized` blocks or `Lock`s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `ConcurrentModificationException` is not only thrown by deletions from the iterated set while iterating. Insertions cause it quite as well. So the likely reason for yours is that your Spring boot controller writes to the map without synchronization with the `deleteFileCache` method.

The obvious solution is to use some thread safe map instead of `HashMap`, for example the `ConcurrentHashMap` mentioned in a couple of the comments.

For example, the documentation of `Spliterator` says:

> … After binding a Spliterator should, on a best-effort basis, throw
>   `ConcurrentModificationException` if structural interference is
>   detected. …

It seems from your stacktrace that the `min` method uses a Spliterator.

Structural changes include both insertions and deletions (they probably don’t include replacing a mapping in the map where only the value is changed).

**Link:** [Documentation of `Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html)